# How to check if the client_id generated is valid for google project

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I have a google project with a client id generated for a OAuth client, 
how do I verify that its a valid one before making other requests using the same client id

Comment: It seems like google oauth services are down at the moment.  Nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Worked fine the whole day, but still not able to figure this out

Comment: Make a call against the API if it doesn't work it will tell you.   If it was created on Google Developer console its a valid id.

Comment: Hey @DaImTo, is there a way to get a json response for this and parse instead of parsing the html response.
I am using this 

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly+openid&response_type=token%20id_token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&immediate=true&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=asdasdas

Comment: Nope authentication request is just an html file.   I have been trying to find a way of doing this as well.